# Spring Boot cant serve css file with Thymeleaf View

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am making an app with Spring Boot.
I have a Thymeleaf view `chat.html` in `resources/templates/chat.html` I include `style.css` stylesheet in it.
When I load the chat.html in browser only html shows without any stylesheet.

Here is chat.html

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
        <link href="styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Chat Web App</title>
    </head>
   ...some irrelevant html ...
    <body>

</body>
</html>
```

I have put the style.css in `resources/static/styles/style.css` as per several other answers  for same problem but no bueno. Perhaps some additional configuration need to be made or i am simply making a dumb typo.

Comment: Use the th:href tag.

Comment: I tried following taken from other answer that suggested the same  ```<link href="../static/styles/style.css" th:href="@{/styles/style.css}" rel="stylesheet">
``` still no css.

Comment: The issue was actually in my CSS file. I have used selectors for classes that erent present in the HTML. The proposed solution and the way I did it before that both work fine now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually in my CSS file :) . Apparently i had selectors for classes that werent present in the html. After removing them the solution proposed in the comments worked fine!